# Workflow not getting triggered?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

so I am having a small issue with one of my workflows that I have created. So once an opportunity is "closed won' and today's date is an exactly a week from the "event date", then a survey email gets sent out. However, this used to work and for some reason, it no longer works. I have checked the time-based workflow monitor and there is nothing in the "Queue". The workflow is active and an email template is attached so I know that is not the problem.

[image]

Comment: It will be difficult to debug this issue with so little detail. Please **[edit]** your post to include the workflow criteria and time based trigger setup.

Comment: i uploaded a screenshot of the workflow criteria and time based trigger setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Time-Based Workflow FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245&language=en_US)

> **Will the pending actions in the queue ALWAYS trigger?**
>
> No. Time-dependent actions remain in the Workflow Queue until processed or the rule criteria for the Workflow Rule are evaluated as "false." If a record no longer matches the rule criteria when the rule is evaluated, Salesforce removes the time-dependent actions queued for that record.
>
> **For example**, an Opportunity Workflow Rule may specify:
>
> - A criteria set to "Opportunity: Status not equals to Closed Won, Closed Lost."
> - An associated time-dependent action with a time trigger set to seven days before the Opportunity close date. If a record that matches the criteria is created on July 1st and the Close Date is set to July 30th, the time-dependent action is scheduled for July 23rd. However, if the Opportunity is set to "Closed Won" or "Closed Lost" before July 23rd, the time-dependent action is automatically removed from the queue.

When your trigger executes, `Event_Date__c = TODAY()` will no longer be true. I'm not sure how this workflow ever fired off the time triggers, but they should be removed from the queue as soon as it is no longer the Event Date.

Comment: That makes more sense, thank for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Event_Date__c = TODAY()` in you criteria, this is handled in Time-Dependent action itself.
When you change this, you have to retrigger WR for all opportunities having `Event Date` within 14 days to have the system to reschedule these 7 and 14 days email followups